# Code to Exclude Column Headings from Transferring to Excel 2007 from Access 2007

Tags: excel, ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

Here's the code which I am using.

It works fine, but I need to know what additional code is required to exclude the column headings.

```
Private Sub Command104ContrDonatWeekly_Click()
On Error GoTo Command104ContrDonatWeekly_Click_Err

    DoCmd.OpenQuery "Contributors Who Donated in Past Week", acViewNormal, acEdit

    xlfile = "C:\Users\Michael1\Desktop\KSN\DistributionListWeekly.xlsb"
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, _
    "Contributors Who Donated in Past Week", xlfile, True, "EmailList"

    Shell "Excel.exe " & xlfile, vbNormalFocus

Command104ContrDonatWeekly_Click_Exit:
    Exit Sub

Command104ContrDonatWeekly_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Command104ContrDonatWeekly_Click_Exit

End Sub
```

Here's some code from

[How to write VBA code to hide all the column and row headings in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624110/how-to-write-vba-code-to-hide-all-the-column-and-row-headings-in-excel)

which I don't quite know where it needs to be placed in with the code I am already using.

```
Private Sub hideHeadings()
  Dim wrkbk As Workbook
  Dim wrksh As Worksheet
  Dim prev As Window

  Set prev = ActiveWindow

  For Each wrkbk In Workbooks
    For Each wrksh In wrkbk.Worksheets
        wrksh.Activate
        ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = False
    Next wrksh
  Next wrkbk

  prev.Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: Unless I am missing something, why not just create a new query that only has the output you want?

Comment: How do you hide an Access query's column heading in datasheet view?

Comment: Ha, Sorry... I misread Column Heading as Column.

Answer (score 1):

From Access:

```
Sub XLTrans()
''Reference: Microsoft ActiveX Data Object x.x Library
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim xl As Object ''Excel.Application
Dim wb As Object ''Workbook

Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Add

''Connection relevant for 2007 or 2010
rs.Open "MyTableOrQuery", CurrentProject.AccessConnection

wb.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs

xl.Visible = True

End Sub
```

Comment: In an MS Access module. It is instead of using TransferSpreadsheet. BTW, it is best to state all your requirements in your initial question along with any solutions you have tried.

Comment: ty, right now I'm getting an Error Invali SQL statement, so Ima work on that

Comment: @HelloWorld What is your sql statement?

Comment: well I have rs.Open "Query1", CurrentProject.AccessConnection,  Query1 just being a placeholder name. Its a parameter query that does calculations base ont he start and end date entered

Comment: @Remou Was there a specific reason for the New ADODB declaration I switched it to DAO and also aded a QueryDef and it seems to work alright.

Comment: @HelloWorld No. I was probably thinking of SQL server at the time :)

Comment: @Remou this help'd a lot I've been researching how to do this all morning ty.

Comment: @HelloWorld. Good, have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using the transferspreadsheet;

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "tbl_one", xlfile, True

Dim xl As Object
Dim wb As Object

Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(xlfile)

xl.DisplayAlerts = False
With wb.Worksheets(1)
    .Rows(1).Delete
End With
wb.Save
xl.Visible = True
```