# Access 2010 Export Query to Specific Excel Range using VBA

Tags: export-to-excel, ms-access-2010

The title pretty much says it all, I'm looking for a way to export this query to a specific column in excel so that I don't have to create a bunch of separate excel files.

The query itself does a calculation using dates and I want to run it for each month of the year. So in pseudo code something like:

```
For i = 1 to 13  
  Export Query with to cell i with parameters 
    StartDate = DateSerial(Me.txtYear, i, 1), 
    EndDate = DateSerial(Me.txtYear, i+1, 1)
  i++
Next
```

Also right now the calc is dubbed As Month but I would be awesome if I could some how get it to change dynamically and have the actual month be the field header.

Comment: I should have not'd that I found code that I believe represents something along the lines of what I wish todo located here: http://www.accessmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/access-externaldata/489/export-data-to-specific-field-in-excel-is-this-possible But I get error 5 something to do with invalid input parameters at the following line:  objXLSheet.Range(strCellRef).CopyFromRecordset rs

Comment: Try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184342/code-to-exclude-column-headings-from-transferring-to-excel-2007-from-access-2007/10196850#10196850

Comment: You might like to post your resolved answer below.

Comment: good point, I'm just not 100% finished, but when I'm done I shall. I'm just fixing up some things.

Comment: @Remou I was busy in the afternoon and left some last error checks for the morning. Right now I am opening a workbook in excel and have an error check for error 1004 that supposedly means "Workbook does not exist". Which is fine and I have a handler but the handler seems to run even when the workbook is in existence and prompts the user with an Overwrite? prompt. I don't even mind that but the problem is that when they click no or cancel error 1004 SaveAs method fail happens. The point of the handler was to create a new WB if it didnt exist but it seems to be hung up on ones that do...

Comment: You seem to have accepted an answer, is this a different question?

Comment: @Remou yes it is, I was just hoping it was something very small and that I wouldn't have to start another question. If you prefer I can and make it an official question.

Comment: The problem is that without code I can only guess what is happening and if you post code here, it changes the question too much at this stage.

Comment: I see your point I have created a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11888018/access-2010-excel-export-1004-error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you can create the query that creates your data, then something along the lines of [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa165427%28v=office.10%29.aspx) should help.

In the code I use to drop data to excel, I use this to write the headers:

```
fldCount = rs.Fields.Count
For iCol = 1 To fldCount
    xlWs.Cells(1, iCol).value = rs.Fields(iCol - 1).Name
Next
```

and then this to write the data into the worksheet in A2

```
xlWs.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
```