# Access 2010 Excel Export 1004 Error

Tags: excel, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have some VBA in Access 2010 that runs a query and exports the results to a column in Excel. The goal here is that when the user presses the required button an excel workbook is opened, if it doesn't exist then it is created. When a new workbook is created the VBA preforms as expected. The issue I'm having is when the workbook already exists.

So after I create an set my excel app object I attempt to open the workbook. When it doesn't exist a 1004 error occurs and I have the following error handler:

```
    Select Case Err
    Case 1004   'Workbook doesn't exist, make it
    xl.Workbooks.Add
    Set wb = xl.ActiveWorkbook
    wb.SaveAs strWorkBook

    Resume Next
```

When the user opens an existing workbook they are prompted with an Overwrite Yes,No,Cancel options. Any response other than yes generates a 1004 error (seems odd 2 different errors having same code #). I was just looking for a way around this, whether it be I write some VBA to automatically accept or I have something else that allows users to say no/cancel. The easiest is preferred, I just don't want an error poping up on them.

Comment: Thought I may have found a solution in the SaveAs conflictResolution but no dice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to rely on error handling to deal with whether or not the Excel file exists.  Use `Dir()` to check whether it exists, and open or create accordingly.

```
If Len(Dir(strFullPathToWorkbook)) > 0 Then
    ' open the workbook '
Else
    ' create the workbook '
End If
```

Use `wb.SaveAs strWorkBook` if this is a new workbook.

Use `wb.Save` if it's an existing workbook.

Comment: That's great but I still have the issue with the SaveAs

Comment: Now for some reason when I go to open an existing workbook it gives off a 1004 error saying it cannot be found

Comment: Okay that's fixed but I still am getting the Overwrite prompt that I have to either hit Yes of an error occurs

Comment: It is fixed now it appears there was a path issue that seemed odd since the first time was a copy paste anyway. Thank you for your help. Next time try not to respond in a _condescending_ _tone_ . I followed the advice you gave so please do not try to act like I was ignoring it.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I was frustrated, which isn't a valid excuse.  I'll delete the offensive comment.